# AWS Route53 - A Record not pointing to EC2 web server

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nameserver, amazon-route53

I have an EC2 server running with the following IP: **15.185.59.214**

I created a Hosted Zone in Route53. I put the domain name as www.awpro.studio.
For some reason though, after creation, it shows www.awpro.studio\057. as the domain name (in the list view). In the hosted zone, I created an A record with the above IP. I left the name field empty.

The domain was bought in Namecheap. I've used the Route53 provided nameservers there. But the domain still does not point to the EC2 server. When I visit www.awpro.studio it says "This site can’t be reached www.awpro.studio’s server IP address could not be found.". Checking the same on Dig shows that there are no records for it. You can find it here: [https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#CNAME/awpro.studio]

Why isn't it being pointed correctly? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Currently, `dig` shows that there are no `NS` records for `awpro.studio`.

If you can see that the nameservers are set in Namecheap, I'd suggest contacting their support.

Comment: Namecheap support told me its correctly pointed to AWS nameservers

Comment: MXToolbox [verifies](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=ns%3aawpro.studio&run=toolpage) there are no name servers for your domain. Log into your registrar (assume NameCheap) and put in the Route53 server names.

Comment: @Tim I contacted NameCheap and they told me its correctly configured and that I should contact my hosting provider (which is EC2)

Comment: When I posted yesterday the NS servers weren't set. Now they are. I guess it took some time to propagate. Things seem to be resolving now, but instead of showing the domain it's forwarding to http://ec2-15-185-59-214.me-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/ which is a bit odd. DNS isn't doing that, something you've configured is doing that.